# How to call multiple Api based on the previous Api success

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to make multiple API call in the same screen, but when one api fails other api should not be called? The below code is working fine. but what I need is , how can I refactor this in a more simpler way?

```
      ApplicationService.requestAppEndPointUrl { success, error in
        if success {
            ApplicationService.appLinkDownload { success, error in
                if success{
                    ApplicationService.requestApplicationSession { success, error in
                        if success {
                            ApplicationService.validateSdk { success, error in
                                if success {
                                    ApplicationService.requestApplicationDetails { success, error in
                                        if success{
                                            print("Success")
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            self.showErrorAlert(error)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    self.showErrorAlert(error)
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            self.showErrorAlert(error)
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    self.showErrorAlert(error)
                }
            }
        }else{
            self.showErrorAlert(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ApplicationService` is a class/struct that you can modify, you could convert the **synchronous** function calls with completion handler to **asynchronous** function calls, using [Swift 5.5 concurrency](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/async-await/). The code would look like:

```
do {
  try await ApplicationService.requestAppEndPointUrl()
  try await ApplicationService.appLinkDownload()
  try await ApplicationService.requestApplicationSession()
  try await ApplicationService.validateSdk()
  try await ApplicationService.requestApplicationDetails()
} catch {
  self.showErrorAlert(error)
}
```

Then, the 1st error would break the call chain, would be cought and shown.
If you had to use the synchronous `ApplicationService` functions, you could convert them to asynchronous functions by using async wrappers as shown in the link cited above.

Answer (score 1):

for this, you need to use **OperationQueue** & ** DispatchGroup** where you can make your API calls in **BlockOperation** and one operation depends on another, and their dispatch group helps you to hold the API calls.

```
func apiCall() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    
    
    let operation1 = BlockOperation {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        ApplicationService.requestAppEndPointUrl {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: Double.random(in: 1...3))
            print("ApplicationService.requestAppEndPointUrl()")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        dispatchGroup.wait()
    }
    
    let operation2 = BlockOperation {
        
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        ApplicationService.appLinkDownload {
            print("ApplicationService.appLinkDownload()")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        dispatchGroup.wait()
    }
    
    operation2.addDependency(operation1)
    
    let operation3 = BlockOperation {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        ApplicationService.requestApplicationSession {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: Double.random(in: 1...3))
            print("ApplicationService.requestApplicationSession()")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        dispatchGroup.wait()
    }
    operation3.addDependency(operation2)
    
    let operation4 = BlockOperation {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        ApplicationService.validateSdk {
            print("ApplicationService.validateSdk()")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        dispatchGroup.wait()
    }
    
    operation4.addDependency(operation3)
    
    let operation5 = BlockOperation {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        ApplicationService.requestApplicationDetails {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: Double.random(in: 1...3))
            print("ApplicationService.requestApplicationDetails()")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        dispatchGroup.wait()
    }
    operation5.addDependency(operation4)
    
    queue.addOperations([operation1, operation2, operation3, operation4, operation5], waitUntilFinished: true)
}
```

I know code is a little bit nasty.

and if you are using swift 5.5 then use **Async await** mentioned by @Reinhard Männer

Comment: make it more clear sir

Comment: @HritikSingh please check again my solution so you can get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a pretty question. So if you don't want to pass data from one api call to the other the solution is pretty easy.

All you have to do is to make a Service Manager that will manage all the service calls.

You can make an enum based on the services you want to call

```
enum ServiceEnum {
   case requestAppEndPointUrl
   case appLinkDownload
   case requestApplicationSession
   case validateSdk
   case requestApplicationDetails
}

enum ServiceState {
   case notStarted
   case inProgress
   case finished
   case failed
}
```

Then you can make a class of the service

```
class Service {
   var service: ServiceEnum
   var serviceState: ServiceState = .notStarted
 
   init(service: ServiceEnum) {
     self.service = service
   }

   func updateState(serviceState: ServiceState) {
     self.serviceState = serviceState
   }
}
```

After that you will need to make the Service Manager

```
class ServiceManager {
   private var services = [Services]()
   private var indexForService: Int {
      didSet {
          self.startServices()
      }
   }
   init() {
      services.append(.requestAppEndPointUrl)
      services.append(.appLinkDownload)
      services.append(.requestApplicationSession)
      services.append(.validateSdk)
      services.append(.requestApplicationDetails)
      indexForService = 0
   }

   func startServices() {
      // Check if the process has ended
      guard indexForService < services.count else {
          // If you want you can call an event here.
          // All the services have been completed
          return 
      }
      
      // Check that we have services to call
      guard services.count > 0 else {
          return
      }

      handleService(service: services[indexForService])
   }

   func haveAllFinished() -> Bool {
       return services.fist(where: { $0.serviceState == .failed || $0.serviceState == .notStarted || $0.serviceState == .inProgress }) == nil
   }
   
   func handleService(service: Service) -> Bool {
     switch(service) {
         case .requestAppEndPointUrl:
          ApplicationService.requestAppEndPointUrl { success, error in
                 let serviceState = success ? .finished : .failed
                 service.updateState(serviceState: serviceState)
                 if success {
                    self.indexForService += 1
                 } else {
                    self.showErrorAlert(error)
                 }
             }
         // Do the same for other services
      }
   }
}
```